# Travel to Italy from the UK - Is the NHS COVID Pass sufficient to fulfil the Green Pass requirements?

Tags: uk, air-travel, covid-19, italy, eu

I will be traveling to Rome, Italy, from the UK, within the next few days and thought to check the Foreign Advice page for Italy.
https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/italy/coronavirus

It states that Italy currently use a 'Green Pass' system, whereby citizens can prove their vaccination/ recovery or negative test status with a digital QR code (equivalent to the EU digital COVID certificate).

I am fully vaccinated (two doses + additional booster) and have my NHS Travel QR codes ready - are these an accepted form of proof to use in Italy? Or do I still need to obtain a 'Green Pass' or 'Super Green Pass' when I arrive?

When I visited Paris, France a couple of months ago, there didn't seem to be an issue anywhere but I just wanted to confirm my NHS Covid Pass for Travel was still suitable for Italy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the QR code generated in the NHS app when you have had two doses plus a booster is accepted as a "Super Green Pass".

This is confirmed by the gov.uk page you linked to; I've emphasised the key points:

> A Green Pass **or a Super Green Pass** (see below) is required for the following...

Then below:

> Italy will accept the **UK's proof of COVID-19 recovery and vaccination record** as the **equivalent to a Super Green Pass** as long as it is in the form of a verifiable QR code.

And:

> Once in Italy, a primary vaccination certificate (demonstrating both doses of a two-dose vaccine or one dose of a one-dose vaccine) serving as a Super Green Pass has a validity of 180 days from the date of the last vaccine or is **valid indefinitely for those who have had a full course plus a booster dose**.

It's a good idea to save a PDF copy, and maybe print some out, so that you're not reliant on your phone and data connection.

Comment: Heh, would help if I read the entire page it seems. Got hung up about the 'Green Pass' so much that I completely missed that part. Thanks for this!

Comment: @nopassport1 To be fair, I wouldn't have been so confident writing this answer if I hadn't been to Italy earlier this year, so have the additional anecdotal evidence that it worked absolutely fine. Enjoy your trip :)

Comment: As a followup, we visited Italy using the NHS Covid Pass without issue. Unsure if they still require this